# split comma in the object key value and read the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, validation, data-manipulation

i have array of object where some key values are set in comma seperated
here below is sample object how it is

```
var data = [{
  "id":1,
  "x, y, z" :"1,2,3"
}, {
  "id":2,
  "x, y, z" :"10,12,153"
}, {
  "id":3,
  "x, y, z" :"9,8,5"
}, {
  "id":4,
  "x, y, z" :"14,87,13"
}]
```

here is the expected output

```
[{
  "id":1,
  "x":1,
  "y":2,
  "z":3
},{
  "id":2,
  "x":10,
  "y":12,
  "z":153
},{
  "id":3,
  "x":9,
  "y":8,
  "z":5
},{
  "id":4,
  "x":14,
  "y":87,
  "z":13
}]
```

here below is code i tried,

```
const outputArray = data.map((item:any, index:number) => {
      let commaHeaders = Object.keys(item)[index]?.split(',');
      console.log(commaHeaders)
      if(commaHeaders && commaHeaders.length >= 2) {
        commaHeaders.map((comma) =>{
          item[comma] = comma.trim();
        })
      }
      return item
});
```

**Note**
the function should be generic, in some case i will get a,b,c as a key values instead of x,y,z
any help or suggestions are really helpful!

Comment: Forgot to tell what is wrong and what kind of output you currently get

Comment: `item:any, index:number` is syntax error in Javascript

Comment: my bad, it's written in TS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```js
function decommafy(obj) {
  const newObj = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (key.includes(",") && typeof value === "string") {
      const keys = key.split(",");
      const values = value.split(",");
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        newObj[keys[i].trim()] = values[i].trim();
      }
    } else {
      newObj[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}

const result = [
  {
    id: 1,
    "x, y, z": "1,2,3",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    "fnef, fnerdl": "farb,forb",
    "zub,zab": "zeeb,zib",
  },
].map(decommafy);

console.log(result);
```

This doesn't automatically cast the values to Numbers, but you can trivially add that.

Comment: thanks man, this is so perfect and perfectly as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could split all key/value pairs (by comma with optional whitespace) and convert finite values to numbers.

```js
const
    data = [{ "id": 1, "x, y, z": "1,2,3" }, { "id": 2, "x, y, z": "10,12,153" }, { "id": 3, "x, y, z": "9,8,5" }, { "id": 4, "x, y, z": "14,87,13" }],
    result = data.map(o => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(o)
        .flatMap(([k, v]) => {
            const
                kk = k.split(/\s*,\s*/),
                vv = v.toString().split(/\s*,\s*/).map(v => isFinite(v) ? +v : v);
                
            return kk.map((k, i) => [k, vv[i]]);
        })    
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
    const outputArray = data.map((item) => {
      // Extract the keys of item
      let keys = Object.keys(item);
      // Find the key with comma
      const commaKey = keys.find((key) => key.includes(','));
      // Extract the properties
      const commaHeaders = commaKey.split(', ');
      // Extract the values
      const commaValues = items[commaKey].split(', ');
      // Assign the right value to the right key in item
      commaHeaders.forEach((key, index) => {
        item[key] = commaValues[index];
      });
      // Delete the original property
      delete item[commaKey];
      return item
});
```

Comment: thanks man, this is so simple and easy to understand